# Customize the PrettyPrint options in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, pretty-print

I'm aware of the writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter option in Jackson, but is there any way to customize it?  See examples below.

If this isn't possible in Jackson, if you can't change pretty print options, then is there another popular JSON library that would do it?

Summary of options to change:

- Don't open multiple containers on the same line
- Don't close and open containers on the same line
- Use 4 spaces as indents instead of 2
- (another option, though I wouldn't use it) Open containers on a new line so that they line up vertically with their closing marker

Example of what it outputs now:

```
[ {
  "id" : "12",
  "payload" : [ {
    "name" : "url",
    "value" : [ {
      "name" : "url",
      "value" : "http://foobar.com"
    } ]
  }, {
    "name" : "tags",
    "value" : [ {
      "name" : "tags",
      "value" : "red"
    }, {
      "name" : "tags",
      "value" : "green"
    }, {
      "name" : "tags",
      "value" : "blue"
    }, {
      ...
```

Example of what I'd like to get:

```
[ 
    {
        "id" : "12",
        "payload" : [
            {
                "name" : "url",
                "value" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "url",
                        "value" : "http://foobar.com"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name" : "tags",
                "value" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "tags",
                        "value" : "red"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "tags",
                        "value" : "green"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "tags",
                        "value" : "blue"
                    },
                    {
                        ...
```

Comment: You can implement a custom [PrettyPrinter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/PrettyPrinter.html) for your use case.

Comment: @Alexey actually that's not a bad idea, thanks!